# A plugin for Protractor to measure e2e coverage

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, test-coverage

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-e2e-coverage) plugin to generate a coverage report. However, it is not working. I am getting error:
Failure during setup: Cannot read property 'outdir' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'outdir' of undefined

Do you know how to resolve this and generate the report?

Comment: My config.js :
exports.config = {

seleniumadress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
 
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  framework: 'jasmine',
 
   specs: ['spec.js'],

   jasmineNodeOpts: {
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000
  },
 plugins: [
    {
      path: '../../node_modules/protractor-e2e-coverage/index.js',
      outdir: '../coverage'
    }
  ]
};

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution.

Specify in your protractor.conf.js a custom script.

```
plugins: [
  {
    path: 'scripts/protractor-e2e-coverage-custom.js'
  }
];
```

In the custom script, set the default value.

```
const coverage = require('protractor-e2e-coverage');
const path = require('path'); 

coverage.outdir = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'test/e2e-stats/report');

var coveragePlugin = new coverage.CoveragePlugin();
```